# how slow down rotation speed when rotating image using matrix.postRotate?

Tags: android, animation, matrix, imageview

I want to slow down the animation speed as I am using below code to rotate `ImageView`.

```
matrix.postRotate(degrees);
```

Comment: Please review, https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this at one point and from what I remember I ended up using a [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator). It went something like this:

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 90f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator updatedAnimation) {
        float animatedValue = (float)updatedAnimation.getAnimatedValue();
        matrix.postRotate(animatedVlaue);
    }
});
animation.start();
```

DISCLAIMER:
The math above is def off, you cant just postRotate the full animated value, you will end up over-rotating (if the animated values are 1, 2, 4, 9, etc then you will end up rotating 1, 3, 7, 16, etc). I cant find the relevant code but I solved it by keeping track of the previous animated value and then just doing postRotate on the delta between that and the current animated value.

Hope that makes sense! Feel free to comment if it doesn't.